# C#:An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I am getting this error in my code in this line:

```
var cid = (from cu in dc.CUsers
           where cu.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
           select cu.CId).FirstOrDefault();
```

I put a breakpoint on this line. Then using the step button I can see that this line is being executed many times until I get this error.

**SOLVED** 
The problem was that I was calling this function OnDataBinding instead of OnReadData (EXT.NET framework).

Comment: check if there is any recursive call surrounding this line

Comment: The obvious issue could be if this is in some way meant to be the provider that ends up *populating* the `User` property of `HttpContext.Current`. Could that be the case?

Comment: [You need to include the exception details and have it show the stack trace](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Click the Copy Exception Details to clipboard button on the exception screen and paste the details here

Comment: Also you propably need to show more of this code, like what is `dc`, what is `dc.CUsers`

Comment: When you say "I can see that this line is being executed many times until I get this error" do you mean *just* that line is being executed many times or does it go through a series of different methods before getting back there? If in doubt the stack trace will tell you the answer to this.

Answer (score 5):

A Stack Overflow exception usually means that you're doing some sort of infinite recursion.  I don't think it has anything to do with that line other than the fact that it's probably one of the more resource-intensive lines in the recursive function.

Once you've hit the break point a few times, have a look at the *stack trace*, to see where that line is getting called from.  If it truly has to do with the stack overflow exception, you'll see the same functions repeated in the stack trace.